# Llamar un objeto de una Lista y remplazarlo por otro

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito llamar un objeto especifico atraves de una lista para guardarlo en otra, quiero hacerlo con el atributo Id, cree un foreach asi pero no me devuelve nada ni siquiera el que esta marcado, y tambien necesito que de esa lista Recomendadas se pase a una lista de Vistas y se borre de recomendadas, no se si me falta algo mas para que esto funcione.

```
foreach (Pelicula A in Recomendadas){
    if (A.Id.Equals(1)){
        Recomendadas.Remove(A)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Necesitamos que agregues el tipo de Pelicula y el tipo de Recomendadas. No sabemos que es ese Remove! igual, esto con linq sale solo, sabias?

Comment: Para empezar, estás modificando la lista (o sea, Recomendadas) en el mismo foreach donde estás recorriendo esa lista. Yo lo que haría sería utilizar un for (sin el each), y recorrer Recomedadas desde el final al principio, hasta donde se es la forma recomendada para eliminar elementos de un enumerable, algo como "for (var i = Recomendadas.Count -1; i >= 0; i--) { if (Recomendadas[i].Id.Equals(1)) {Recomendadas.RemoveAt(i); break}}

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estás utilizando listas, lee un poco sobre expresiones lambda, para encontrar un objeto específico de la lista, sólo necesitas utilizar la propiedad `FirstOrDefault` de esta manera:

```
var objeto = Recomendadas.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == tuId);
```

Esto te saca el objeto específico de la lista que luego podes almacenar en el objeto que deseas.